# Using powershell to fill a web text box and press a button

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, button, web, click

I am trying to use powershell to automate opening IE and placing a value inside a text box and pressing a button.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 
cls
$orderID = "text box entry" 
$smoURL = "URL"
$iterator = 1;

Write-Host ("ID = $orderID")

$orderIDTextBox = "txtOrderID"
$searchButton = "btnSearch"

$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("$smoURL")
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000} 

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

$ie.Document.getElementById("$orderIDTextBox").value = "$orderID"
$Submit = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("$btnSearch") 
$Submit.click()
```

I've got the site to open but when I try populate the text field I get this error message:

[image]

[image: This is the inspect element on the webpage.]

This is the inspect element on the webpage.

Comment: You may want to add a check to verify that your `$ie.Document`'s properties are still there. Depending on how your are navigating between DNS zones, you might run into an issue where `.Document` loses all properties. You might want to check if you're hitting that site via HTTPS and if that's what's causing you to lose the values. In that case you might want to disable TLS (but only in testing, not a good choice if in a production workflow).